# Set controller property to first model

Tags: ember.js

I want to set a controller property to the first object of the models but can't get the syntax right.

My application route...

```
model: function(){
    return this.store.find('group');
}
```

And then in my application controller, I'm trying something like...

```
activeGroup: function(){
        return this.get('model.firstObject');
    },
```

I've got a function a little later to set activeGroup to whichever is chosen, but I want it to be set as the first (or any) class by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model hook should look like this:

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('group').then(function(results) {
      return results.get('firstObject');
    });
}
```

JSBIN: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kukeji/1/edit

..or if you still want to use the full model array elsewhere... just use in your Controller

`theFirstModel: Ember.computed.alias('model.firstObject')`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/movuzo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Second option there was exactly what I was after! New to Ember - just realised it should have been a computed property, but it still would have taken me an age to work out the syntax. Much appreciated!